# How to implement a cold storage for unused Symfony data?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am running a `Symfony 2.8` web app which allows the user to store and manage several different data entities

Over time the database grew bigger and bigger where a lot of data belongs to inactive/abandoned accounts which are no longer used.

Of course it quite easy to identify these accounts and the corresponding data can simply be deleted. However, I can never be sure if the users may return to his account and re-starts using his data. Thus I would like to implement a two step process:

1. If the user has not access his data for 3 month the data is moved from the production database to a cold storage. This would be just another database which holds the necessary tables to save the user data.
2. If the user has not accessed his account for 12 month the account and the data will be deleted.

**How to setup such a cold storage?**

According to the Symfony docs it should be no problem to work with two different `EntityManagers` to connect to two different databases.

But how to manage and setup the cold storage database?

How do I tell Symfony/Doctrine to create the tables for `EntityA` and `EntityB` entities (the data) in the production database as well as in the cold storage database but the table for `EntityC` only in the production db (e.g. the user settings)?

How to move the entities from one database/EntityManger to the other? Is there a more effective solution to do this instead of just loading the entity from one EntityManger and persisting it in the other?

Is there any best practice to solve this?

Comment: I would think that inactive records aren't going to cause any significant performance/storage differences.  For what you're doing, you should be able to define multiple entity managers/connections using the same entities, and since entities are just plain classes you can persist to a different entity manager and shouldn't have any issues.